# Methods for organizing/showing algorithm that is coded in C or MATLAB

Tags: c, algorithm, matlab

Is there any recommendations for how to show what your code is doing (C or MATLAB)?  Imagine if your code is really long and you have a lot of functions in your program, what is the best way to document the program?  I know Java IDEs have a way to ingest comments and spit them back out into a document that shows all the functions, and their inputs and outputs. I don't think C or MATLAB has this feature.  At this point, I am thinking comments are the only way to show what is going on in the code, but it may confuse the reader if they have to look through the raw code along side the comments.  The second option would be to write out the algorithm in a text editor such as Microsoft Word.  Is there an industry standard for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If readings through the code confuses the reader, you are programming wrong. Code should be self-documenting. Comments exist to clarify the larger structure of the code or explain the rationale behind choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Java uses is [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html).

For C, you can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

I also saw [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab) which suggests you can use Doxygen with matlab too!

Comment: JavaDoc and Doxygen are for documenting the API, not the code.

Answer (score 3):

The mother of all literate programming is http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/cweb.html
cweb. The father is Knuth.

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of MATLAB actually do have some features very similar to this. If you implement your MATLAB code in object-oriented classes, MATLAB will [auto-generate documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brubzjb-1.html#brubz7_-1) for you by just typing `doc myClassName` - it's really quite similar to Doxygen. If you're not using object-oriented code, you can use MATLAB [publishing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f6-22451.html) to generate a document from your scripts and functions.

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)'s C support is quite good. It supports JavaDoc style and Qt style markup comments, as well as some additional features. See [the manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) for examples of what the markup looks like. I don't have an example of the output ready to hand, but it's quite customizable.

The [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) project, which implements a language and environment that's effectively a superset Matlab's, uses [texinfo](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) to document its functions. You can see an example of the markup in the [Documentation Tips](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Documentation-Tips.html#Documentation-Tips) section of the manual. I recommend scrolling to the bottom of the page to view a complete markup example rather than reading the lengthy explanation that precedes it. I have little experience with texinfo beyond using help from within Octave, but I believe the online manual was generated from texinfo sources, so it seems sufficiently capable.

Comment: “effectively a superset Matlab's”. Not at all true. Octave tries to emulate MATLAB, and they have added syntax in the past that extends the MATLAB language, and some of these features now prohibit them from replicating newer MATLAB syntaxes (e.g. the meaning of the `"`). So now Octave and MATLAB have a partially overlapping syntax, if you use only the common subset you can write code that works on both.